# Once I authenticate a user with OneDrive, how would I go about getting their Xbox live gamertag using the REST framework?

Tags: ios, onedrive

Mostly I am looking for the endpoint in the OneDrive REST api for Xbox live information, I've looked everywhere for it and can't find it anywhere. I know how to retreive information from a user's profile, I just don't know where to look for this specific information.

Thank you!

Supporting information:

- link to OneDrive SDK for iOS: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn631816.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately XBox Live is not tied to OneDrive, and as such the LiveSDK will not provide you access to the Gamertag. If there an XBox Live API you'd need to use that, but since there isn't there isn't really anything I can recommend to do what you ask.